# Is there a dummy lvalue that can be used when nothing is to be executed?

Tags: c, embedded, language-lawyer

Consider the following C99 function:

```
void port_pin_set(const bool value, const uint8_t pin_mask)
{
    if (value) {
        PORT |= pin_mask;
    } else {
        PORT &= ~pin_mask;
    }
}
```

With `PORT` being a `define`, for example:

```
#define PORT (P1OUT)
```

Is there a way to redefine `PORT` so that:

- it is accepted as an lvalue,
- the function does not do anything.

What I want to do is to keep the function source as is, while compiling it to do nothing.

**Edit**: I am aware that using such an lvalue might not be the best solution. I am not looking for the best solution for this specific problem, I am interested in the language itself. This is a theoretical question, not a pragmatic one.

Comment: I think the real question here is why do you want to do this?  While an interesting C preprocessor magic question, I doubt you really need to do this.

Comment: I am mostly curious. I would have removed the file from the compilation command, but the function has an inline definition in a header file `#include`d at multiple places.

Comment: You could just ifded the body of the function

Comment: Sure, there are better solutions, and ifdefing the function out is one of them. But now that I've wondered, I thought I'd check here if there is a way to implement a fake lvalue that just flushes its content down the drain.

Comment: Is this intended for C11, C99 or C89? Different dialects have different (im)possibilities... Added tag [tag:language-lawyer]

Comment: I really don't see how this question makes any sense, or how it could be useful to anyone beyond this very specific odd case. Looking at the answers generated from it, the question is certainly not helping anyone to become better programmers, but rather the opposite. The proper way to make a function not to do anything is to remove the contents entirely, perhaps through a compiler switch. Or even better, remove the whole function from the program if possible.

Comment: @Lundin: this is definitely how I will do it. The answer I accepted is *not* something I will do in real life. The language-lawyer tag added by Johan Bezem was spot on: I am interested in the language itself, not if it is a good idea in this or any specific case. I learned that compound literals can be used as lvalues, and surely learning the language in depth is not useless?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C99 has compound literals that can be used for such a task. Their syntax is a cast followed by an initializer:

```
#define PORT ((int){0})
```

should do it in your case, only that you might get some warnings about unused values or so.

Any decent compiler will optimize assignments to such compound literal out.

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I was looking for, I had a feeling this was possible. You made me read about compound literals again, thanks!

Comment: As stated in the edit of my original question, this is not how I would implement it (ifdefing instead is more readable). But my question was aimed at language constructs, and this answer just nailed it.

Answer (score 8):

You can define a variable of the same type as your `P1OUT` (say, `unsigned char`), make it available in the header, and define it in one of the sources, like this:

Header:

```
extern unsigned char dummy_P1OUT;
#define PORT (dummy_P1OUT)
```

C file:

```
unsigned char dummy_P1OUT;
```

Usages:

```
PORT &= ~pin_mask;

if (PORT & pin_mask) {
    blink_led();
}
```

Comment: Please could you explain how this solves the OP's problem (forcing the compiler to generate no code.)

Comment: @aix I read "compiling it to do nothing" differently from "forcing the compiler to generate no code": my understanding of the OP's intention is that he wants the result that does not change things relevant to his program, similar to forwarding output of a program to `/dev/null` on UNIX.

Comment: Fair enough. I am not sure what the OP intended, but this interpretation also makes sense.

Comment: but this is really suboptimal, as the compiler can't know that the value isn't used somewhere else. In C99 there is a way to avoid that, please see my answer.

Comment: @JensGustedt Compound literals of C99 are nice, and I agree that one should use them if there's support in the compiler. However, compilers in the embedded world have traditionally lagged their mainstream counterparts: I remember working with pre-ANSI embedded compilers well into the late nineties, and even the ones that claimed ANSI compatibility would sometimes misbehave on the new ANSI syntax. Unfortunately, I do not remember the details - I've been out of the embedded world for well over a decade. But when I see "embedded", I read "archaic", and prefer compatible solutions over newer ones.

Comment: I understand your feelings about embedded compilers. Things are getting better though, and my compiler is C99-compliant (there are some that claim they are although they are not). It was an important criterion for my choice of microcontroller and compiler vendor. Your comment is still valid, backward compatibility of source code should be considered.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it in C99:

```
#ifdef PORT
#undef PORT
#endif

#define PORT int x = 0; x
```

for your case. But I suggest you put the whole code between `#ifdef`'s instead of redefining `PORT`:

```
void port_pin_set(const bool value, const uint8_t pin_mask)
{
#ifdef BUILD_PORT_PIN_SET
    if (value) {
        PORT |= pin_mask;
    } else {
        PORT &= ~pin_mask;
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Surely, this would prevent `PORT` being used in the middle of a block, or several times per block, not to mention the possibility of there being a user variable called `x`. (I am assuming the OP wants a reasonably generic solution, as opposed to one that works just for this one example.)

Comment: @aix This was aimed at his specific example. It does appear to be specific.

Comment: you can't declare a variable in the middle of the block in C

Comment: Nope, the case that made me wonder is very similar to the pasted code, but I am interested in a generic solution.

Comment: @MK: C99, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: New compilers have the `__COUNTER__` macro, which can help generate unique variable names.

Comment: your proposal is a bad one. never hide things inside a macro that could change the control flow of the program. E.g if in the example you'd omit the `{}` the code would explode.

Comment: @JensGustedt I did specify "for the code he has posted". Also, I'm suggesting he doesn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not an `lvalue` directly, but I hope it will serve your purpose. Try

```
#define PORT if (0) P1OUT
```

It should effectively null the full statement. You may get some warnings, but that should be surmountable IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

There are perversions in C++ that may do the trick. For instance, you may define `PORT` to return you an object by value, which implements the `|=` and `&=` operators.

In C I can figure-out a way the following way: define an integer variable at the beginning if the function, then `PORT` may by defined to either this variable or the relevant one (`P1OUT` in your case).

When `PORT` is defined to a local variable - you may hope that compiler will omit this code: assigning a local variable a value that is not used.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the statement below on ubuntu and it doesn't write to the first character of the environment variable PATH, where it does on Windows. However by definition it does cause undefined behavior.

```
#define PORT (*(uint8_t*)(getenv("PATH")))
```

So to make it safe one can define a dummy environment value elsewhere in the program and continue to set that instead.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef PORT
#undef PORT
#endif

#define SETDUMMYPORT (putenv("dummyPORT=x"))
#define PORT (*(uint8_t*)(getenv("dummyPORT")))
```

Somewhere in the program set the dummy environment variable:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SETDUMMYPORT;
}
```

Then PORT can be used as you have in your question.

Comment: wow, using `getenv` to simulate compound literals, never have seen that. This is really thinking differently :) Unfortunately your solution is a very dangerous one. The `man` page of `getenv` says:  *The  caller  must take care not to modify this string, since that would change the environment of the process.*

Comment: Right, I'm not saying this is safe, and I even stated it in my first paragraph. However this mechanism is controlled, but I have to say that C certainly lends itself to this kind of trickery.

Comment: no, modern C has a mechanism to produce temporary lvalues that is perfectly suited for the job. Please see my answer.